# Photo sharing site/app that allows others to upload to my stream?

Tags: facebook, photos, image-uploading

My organization is launching some local programs that they want to build up using social media.  We already have some Facebook integration (likes, comments, etc.), but they would like people to be able to upload photos of themselves participating in these events.  I was unable to figure out how to do this via Facebook, and we don’t have the time or resources to do this as a full-blown web app on our site.

- Is anyone able to point me to a resource on doing this with
  Facebook--something that makes more sense than the jumble of info on
  their developer site?
- Anyone aware of a photo sharing site that has an “anonymous
  upload” or similar feature?  Some form of moderation tools would
  also be necessary (for obvious reasons).
- Any other easy-to-implement photo sharing plugin that would not
  require users to sign up for a custom service?  (Facebook would be
  OK since we’re already using that.)

I've tried searching for this many different ways on Google, but pretty much everything comes up for accessing one's own photos, not uploading to a separate group's.  I've looked thru quite a few photo sharing sites too (flickr, photobucket, fotki, etc) but again, mostly they cover uploading only your own photos.

Thanks.